# Boundedness of a sequence in the dual of $l^q$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, lp-spaces, dual-spaces

Let $1\leq p<\infty$ and $q$ be the conjugate exponent of $p$. Suppose that $\lbrace a^n \rbrace_{n=1}^{\infty} \subset \ell^q$ in a sequence in $\ell^q$ such that $f_{a^n}(x) \mapsto 0~( n \mapsto \infty)$ for all $x \in \ell^p$ where $f_{a^n}(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_i^{(n)}x_i$. Show that the sequence $\lbrace a^n \rbrace_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is bounded, i.e., there exists $M\geq0$ such that $\lVert a^n\rVert_q\leq M$ for all $n$.

I get across with a theorem in Bryan P. Rynne Book  which shows that $f_{a^n}$ defines a linear functional $f_{a^n} \in (\ell^q)'$ with $\lVert f_{a^n}\rVert=\lVert a^n\rVert_q$. I think it will help but I am still confused how to prove the statement above

Comment: Your two paragraphs are not coherent with each other. In your first paragraph, $f_{a^n}$ is not a linear functional but a linear map  (and it is not entirely obvious to me what the codomain would be, and it what sense it would go to zero). In your second paragraph, you talk of $f_{a^n}$ as a linear functional.

Comment: Do you mean my second paragraph does not help to prove my question?

Comment: It seems to talk about different things. The way your question is phrased, I don't even know what $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a^nx_n$ means.

Comment: About the edit: still not entirely sure what you mean. What's $i$ now?

Comment: i have edited it again @MartinArgerami

Comment: Now it makes sense. So yes, your second paragraph is related to a certain extent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\lbrace a^n \rbrace_{n=1}^{\infty} \subset l^q$  and $x\in l^p$,  consider $J(a^n)(x)=x(a^n)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} a_i^{(n)}x_i.$ Since the series converges to $0,$ each element of  $\left \{ J(a^n) \right \}$ is pointwise bounded, so by Banach-Steinhaus, there is an $M<\infty $ such that $\|J(a^n)\|<M$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$. But since $y\mapsto J(y)$ is an isometry, it follows that $\|a^n\|<M$ as well.

Comment: how could you say that $y \mapsto J(y)$ is an isometry?

Answer (score 1):

You have a sequence that converges weakly to zero, and you want to conclude that it is bounded. What you need is to use the [Uniform Boundedness Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_boundedness_principle).

Comment: I see. is it equivalent to say that if $f_{a^n}(x) \mapsto 0~( n \mapsto \infty)$ for all $x \in l^p$ then $\lbrace a^n \rbrace_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges coordinatewise to zero?.

Comment: Isn't convergence to zero overkill? All you need is weak convergence right?

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: @MartinArgerami, how to show the equivalence?? I want to show that $Lim_{n \to \infty} a_i^n=0$ for each $i \geq 1$

Comment: Not sure what equivalence you are talking about. What you asked for is more than $\lim_n A^n_i\to0$, you asked that $\|a^n\|$ is uniformly bounded, and you got a proof in the other answer.